# Efficient way to calculate non-na rows vs NA rows in a column

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm looking for a way to efficiently and easily calculate the ratio between non-NA values and NA values in a column.

The way I know is through the use of dplyr, code below

```
Data %>% count(filter(!is.na(x2012))) / count(filter(is.na(x2012)))
```

Now is there an easier way? I thought `n_unique` in the `dplyr` package could be something, but then if you have several identical observations the ratio won't be right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for particular function, base `R` you can simply do:

```
colSums(is.na(df))/colSums(!is.na(df))
#  a   b   c 
#2.0 0.5 Inf
```

For a particular set of columns:

```
colSums(is.na(df))/colSums(!is.na(df))  # works also with one value aka 'a'
```

**Data:**

```
 df = data.frame(a=c(NA,NA,4),b=c(NA,1,2),c=c(NA,NA,NA))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could write short helper functions to calculate:

**Ratio of non-`NA` to `NA` values**

(It will return `Inf` if there are zero `NA` values):

```
valid_ratio <- function(vec){
  sum(!is.na(vec)) / sum(is.na(vec))
}
```

**Percent of records that are NA**

(conveys same information, easier to interpret):

```
perc_NA <- function(vec){
  sum(is.na(vec)) / length(vec)
}
```

You could use them with dplyr's `summarise` like this:

```
mtcars %>%
  summarise(percent_NA = perc_NA(am))

  percent_NA
1          0
```

(there are no NA values in `mtcars$am`)

Comment: OP seems to want #notNA / #NA, ratio not percent.

Comment: Good catch, though it seems to me like a less clear way to encode the same information.  It also will return `Inf` instead of 0-1 values.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, not a very good way to go. You might add that point to the answer as long as you're still including `per_NA`.

Answer (score 1):

`count` works fine:

```
data.frame(a=rep(c(1,NA),c(3,7))) %>% 
  count(     isNA  = is.na(a) ) %>% 
  summarise( ratio = n[!isNA] / n[isNA] )

      ratio
      (dbl)
1 0.4285714
```

This is the ratio 3/7, correct for the example data in the first line.